# Display an image from an int array in tkinter, with colour

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, tkinter

I am aiming to display an image from the data received from a thermal camera connected to a raspberry pi in a Tkinter window.  I have got the data from the pi (which is in a single list 768 int values long (32*24)) which I think can be converted into a NumPy array.  I have been looking at similar solutions and found some very promising examples however they don't function as I would hope them to. However, I imagine that is because I have entered the data incorrectly.

The ideal outcome would be to have an image displayed in colour (Purple, red, yellow, etc) however I have no idea and cannot find after looking for a while how to achieve this

Hope I have explained what the problem is

```
# Example code from StackOverflow: @Adrian W
import tkinter as tk

import numpy as np


def _photo_image(image: np.ndarray):
    height, width = image.shape
    data = f'P5 {width} {height} 255 '.encode() + image.astype(np.uint8).tobytes()
    return tk.PhotoImage(width=width, height=height, data=data, format='PPM')


root = tk.Tk()

array = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]])
img = _photo_image(array)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor="nw", image=img)

root.mainloop()
```

The code above displays an example from another question and this displays a black square on a canvas.  The reason it is black is because 1 and 9 have basically no difference in shade I think it must go up to 1000.

But that code^ works fine for B&W, the same post showed a colour version but the example code didn't work

```
def _photo_image(image: np.ndarray):
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    ppm_header = f'P6 {width} {height} 255 '.encode()
    data = ppm_header + cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB).tobytes()
    return tk.PhotoImage(width=width, height=height, data=data, format='PPM')
```

^Doesn't work, and even if it did I'm not sure how to turn an array/list of int into the data it would need for colour, possibly HEX codes or something

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: please focus your question. you appear to have multiple issues. -- the thermal camera gives single-channel data, and you want to apply a "colormap". is that the core of your question? -- I'd recommend getting the basics to work first, without Tkinter. use matplotlib to get a single frame of data displayed (matplotlib's plotting can apply colormaps implicitly). then you can use [OpenCV to apply a colormap](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d50/group__imgproc__colormap.html) and keep that colored version of the picture. *then* you can get that displayed in Tkinter.

Comment: use PIL/pillow to convert numpy array to PIL Image, and PIL Image to ImageTk.PhotoImage, which is compatible with Tkinter  https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageTk.html when you have color data, pay attention to channel order (OpenCV's native order is BGR, PIL/pillow and Tkinter may expect RGB)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have been able to get the data from the camera to display in black and white with some success, just the image is displayed very small which I can change later.  It is just the colour, which I will look into via the link you send.  The data the camera gives are int values ranging from 1-200 will putting those into an array work with the method you have given?
Thank you for the help